# Python unhashable dict

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a dict and feed the date to Jinja2 template by using title,date and link
But when I try to  build the dict i get "unhashable dict"

```
d = {

    {

    "title":"SOme title",
    "date":2007,
    "link":"somelink"
    },

    {

    "title":"SOme2 title",
    "date":2007,
    "link":"somelink"
    },

}


print d
```

Is there anyway around this problem?Or should I convert it to a JSOn object?

Comment: Your variable **d** is not a dictionary. It is a list of dictionaries. Try `d = [{...}, {...}]`

Comment: That's because that's not the proper format of a dictionary. Look closely, you have two key-less dicts inside a dict. You might possibly want what @JoseVarez presented, which is a list of dicts.

Comment: why don't you use a list of dict?

Comment: You are trying to make `d` a `set` of `dict`s, and set members have the same limitations as dictionary keys - they must be hashable, which dictionaries are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that what you are trying to create is a set of dictionaries - the outer {} is set notation.

Each item in a set must be hashable, you need to build a list :

```
d = [

    {

    "title":"SOme title",
   "date":2007,
    "link":"somelink"
    },

    {

    "title":"SOme2 title",
    "date":2007,
    "link":"somelink"
    }

]
```